# Temporary files are not deleted even if ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES is set to false

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
Centos 6.9 
ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES = false
version ansible 2.8.1
/tmp/.ansible-root/tmp/
```

Regarding temporary files deletion:

1. If the task fails, won't tmp be deleted?
2. If I abort the playbook during execution, the tmp will not be deleted?

The reason for my question is that temporary files are not deleted on some servers and when their number is large, they cause my tasks to fail on those servers.

Comment: 2.8 is [EOL](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#ansible-core-support-matrix) since May 2022. I would clean such tmp regularly from cron. To avoid hazards, lock the box, for example, `/var/lock/ansible.sanity`, or test `fstat /tmp/.ansible-root/tmp/*`.

Answer (score 0):

The currently existing description hardly contains any reliable information and several different questions. Let's try to give a general overview.

> **"*If I abort the playbook during execution, the `/tmp/.ansible-root/tmp/` will not be deleted?*"**

Maybe or probably not, since it couldn't call [`self.cleanup`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aansible%2Fansible%20self.cleanup&type=code) as it became interrupted.

> **"*If the task fails, won't `/tmp` be deleted?*"**

It depends probably on how it failed. See above ...

> **"*Temporary files are not deleted on some servers?*"**

Since there are several dependencies you may have a look into [When does `/tmp` get cleared?](https://serverfault.com/a/377349/448950) and [How is the `/tmp` directory cleaned up?](https://askubuntu.com/q/20783/774046)